# JQuery Tag It - Edit tags inline

Tags: jquery, tag-it

I have used jQuery tagit which will accept email addresses. I have validated tags for email format. I want to know if it can also edit the tags if user has typed something wrong. Right now we have to remove the tag and reenter if something goes wrong.

Thanks in Advance

```
 $("#singleFieldTags").tagit({
        singleField: true,
        singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'),
        beforeTagAdded: function (event, ui) {
            //email validation code
        }
    });


    <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
     <input id="mySingleField" />
```

Comment: I don't think it have edit functionality

Comment: check this one http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/

Answer (score 1):

A [solution](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/315) was posted on GitHub that has this functionality.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgmv2qvz/1/) that allows you to edit the tags.

Essentially you need to use the `onTagClicked` parameter and give it a custom function:

```
 onTagClicked: function(event, ui) {
                var elem = $(ui.tag);
                var input = $('<input type="text" id="replaceInput" value="'+ ui.tagLabel + '" />');
                temp = ui.tagLabel;
                input.bind('blur',function(){
                    var instance = $("#mySingleField").data("tagit");
                    $(this).closest('.tagit-label').empty().append($(this).val());
                    var oldValue = temp;
                    var tags = instance.assignedTags();

                    for(var i = 0;i < tags.length;i++){
                        if (tags[i] === oldValue){
                            tags[i] = $(this).val();
                        }
                    }
                    instance._updateSingleTagsField(tags);
                });                 
                elem.find('.tagit-label').empty().append(input);
                input.focus();
            }
```

Now when you click the tag you will see that you can edit it.